# Javascript affect a div on hover

Tags: javascript, html

Hello guys i have just written this code.All I want is simply hover the cursor over this buttons and affect the div that's on their right side.
 The problem i have now is that i can't link any image.Only colors.But i don't want colors.
I know that's is simple but is slipping my mind right now.

> `<script> function chbg(color){document.getElementById('container2').style.backgroundColor=color;}
>   </script>`

```
<button id="button1" onmouseover="chbg('red')" onmouseout="chbg('whitesmoke')"></button>
```

Comment: And what `<div>`s would those be? You'll need to show the relevant HTML, I'm afraid, before we can realistically provide any help.

Comment: Setting `.style.backgroundImage = 'url(http://path/to/image.png)'` doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
function chimage(url) {
    document.getElementById('container2').style.backgroundImage = 'url('+url+')';
}
</script>

<button id="button1" onmouseover="chimage('/path/to/hoverimage.jpg')" onmouseout="chimage('/path/to/plainimage.jpg');"></button>
```

Comment: I tried but the path of the image isn't working.For example:
 onmouseover="chimage('images/lin.png')"

Comment: Nope!Searched letter by letter.Can you please specify the .style.backgroundImage='url('+url+')';}

Comment: I just tested, it should work if the URL is correct. Is the `images` directory a subdirectory of the one that contains the web page?

Comment: Try using the full URL in case your relative URL is not correct.